# Update a record in table1 if table2 has updates (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, I have 2 tables (currently MyISAM). 
Let's call them table1 and table2.

table1 has:

```
id
passwd
full_name
email
```

table2 has:

```
user_id
book (the book's title)
```

Basically, a user can rent books, and a row is created in table2, with records about the user_id, and the book title the user rented.

In table1, I would like to add a column called 'books_rented'.

In PHP, I can calculate all the rows that x user_id has, and it will return how many books that person rented. 
However, I would like to know if it's possible to do that within MySQL itself, it would seem more optimal to me.

PS.: I am giving books as an example as I thought it would make it simpler, but the tables are actually employer/employee relational. If an employee deletes his account, then it won't really be optimal doing it with PHP as it would need to wait until the employer logs in again to update this. I can't really do this with PHP unless I run a cron job which I don't really like.

Comment: have you tried `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE user_id=1`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I've added a PS to my post which explains why I'm not opting for this yet.

Comment: It's just like asking why I should store birth date instead of my age.

Comment: I understand that, but still not getting how I should go on about solving my issue.

Comment: Are you asking how to make this update happen automatically whenever table2 is updated? Use a `trigger`.

Comment: Yes Barmar, that's right. Doing this would allow me to not have to code updates in PHP whenever an employee deletes his account, or when an employer deletes an employee. And will be helpful for other stuff. Will check about trigger, thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Triggers are exactly what I was looking for. [Great tutorial about it](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/introduction-to-mysql-triggers/).

Answer (score 0):

what is relation between that 2 tables, i assume that table1.id with table2.id.

```
update table1 set books_rented=(select count(*) from table2 where user_id=id)
```

Please try this at your dev machine first.

Answer (score 0):

I think adding the `books_rented` column is necessary. You can just simply `query` it to get the quantity of books that a specific user has rented.

```
SELECT T1.id
    , T1.passwd
    , T1.full_name
    , T1.email
    , IFNULL(COUNT(T2.book), 0) AS books_rented
    FROM table1 T1
    LEFT JOIN table2 T2 ON T2.user_id = T1.id
    GROUP BY T1.id
```

I suggest that you work with your design, since there are instances that you will be:

- renting the same book (will that add to the count of books rented?)
- are you counting only the books that are currently being borrowed? Or all the books that have been rented before are included?

Since `users` and `books` are `many to many relationship`, you need to add a [JUNCTION TABLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table). So you will end up with: `users`, `books` and `userbooks`.

Comment: Hi Kael thanks for your answer.

If a user rents a book, he cannot rent the same again.
When the user returns the book, his row is deleted.
Therefore, the amount of rows a user has, is the amount of books he currently has rented.

Comment: If that's the case, then the query in my answer will do it. Just add a comment if you need more questions, or you can accept my answer. Thanks!